# Can't execute my query

Tags: php, error-handling

My query doesn't seem to execute, i can't figure out why though.
If you know any alternative or need more information or code to this please let me know.

The error: http://gyazo.com/5555adb8d7c0d447b23176c3f07ce687

Code:

```
if(isSet($_POST["submit"])){
    $naamgroep=$_POST["groepnaam"];
    $specialiteit=$_POST["specialiteit"];
    $eisen=$_POST["eisen"];
    $datum=$_POST["datum"];
    $tijdstipvan=$_POST["van"];
    $tijdstiptot=$_POST["tot"];
    $aantpers=$_POST["personen"];

    if(isSet($naamgroep) && strlen($naamgroep) > 2){
        if($specialiteit){
            if($eisen){
                if($datum){
                    if($tijdstipvan){
                        if($tijdstiptot){
                            if($aantpers >= 1){
                                $query = $connection->prepare("
                                    INSERT INTO groepen (naamgroep, Specialiteit, eisen, datum, tijdstip, maxaantalpersonen, omschrijving, leden, eigenaar) 
                                    VALUES (:naamgroep, :specialiteit, :eisen, :datum, :tijdstip, :maxaantalpersonen, :omschrijving, :leden, :eigenaar)
                                ");

                                $query->bindValue(":naamgroep", $naamgroep, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $query->bindValue(":specialiteit", $specialiteit, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $query->bindValue(":eisen", $eisen, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $query->bindValue(":datum", $datum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $query->bindValue(":tijdstip", trim($tijdstipvan)."-".trim($tijdstiptot), PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $query->bindValue(":maxaantalpersonen", $aantpers, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                                $query->bindValue(":eigenaar", $_SESSION["gebruiker"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            }            
                        }                
                    }                    
                }                            
            }
        }
    }
}
if(isSet($_POST["submit1"])){
    $omschrijving=$_POST["omschrijving"];
    $afbeelding=$_POST["afbeelding"];

    if($omschrijving && strlen($omschrijving) > 20){
        $query->bindValue(":omschrijving", $omschrijving, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}
if(isSet($_POST["submit2"])){
    $leden=$_POST["vriend"];

    if($leden){
        $query->bindValue(":leden", $leden, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $query->execute();
    }                             
}
```

Comment: In your Fields which you get data from `_POST` method and then this data store in the variable so you check that this variables are set properly and then check in your database any fields `Not Null ` constrain apply and then at the `INSERT` time you sends `NULL` so get this error.

Answer (score 0):

1.) First replace isSet with isset
2.)Write query like this ..example :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO dummy(firstname, lastname, email) 
VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
```